# How to make a tooltip popup when user mouses over a text inside <ins> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

ok, I have a custom `<ins>` tag as following:

```
ins{
    color:blue; 
    font-weight:500;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ins:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

I want that when user mouses over the text inside an `<ins>` tag, then a small tooltip will popup saying that "This is inserted text".

So, basically, we should modify the `ins:hover` like the following:

```
ins:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    text-decoration:underline;
    tooltip:"This is inserted text";
}
```

Can we achive something like that?

If we can't do thing like that then

Is there any html basic tag that has tooltip popup, which meets my requirement?

**Note:** Basic tag means any tag that can work without needing any attibute. For security reason, I can't use any attribute in basic html tag.

Comment: If you absolutely can’t use something simple like the `title` attribute, then probably using CSS generated content with `:before`/`:after` is the next simplest thing.

Comment: How is it "secure" to not have an attribute? If you place the tooltip text in CSS it's just as visible... ?

Comment: the hacker can put the malicious code into the attribute, besides my app can not validate all the html tag issue. Safety first.

Comment: What “hacker”? You did not even specify where this content is supposed to _come_ from, so talking about “security” without any such context is rather nonsense. And taking a simple _text_ the user enters somewhere and putting it into a `title` attribute has no security implications either, if one knows the least basic thing about context-aware escaping.

Comment: By the way, the code i use for sanitizing HTML does not accept any atributes. User can out liek <a onClick="callMalicious();"> or thing like that. ALso SanitizingHTML class is simple & I don't want to change it. Besides, the requirement above is not the most important one in my WebApp

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [tooltip demo](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/Dewdo) which uses jquery to display a tooltip. This may be a possible solution for you.

It uses a div container to store individual tooltips, which are shown/displayed and positioned when a user hovers over a trigger point. Each trigger is linked to an individual tooltip by specifying a tooltip id. The positioning of the tooltip is based on the mouse cursor position and the location of the trigger point with regard to the window (if the window has scrolled down).

Hope this is of use.

A css solution might use the `content:` rule. Perhaps also using the `:before` or `:after` selectors.

```
ins:hover::after{content:"tooltip text"};
```

However this approach may become quite cumbersome when used multiple times across the entire site.

Comment: ur tooltip demo is for tag with attribute, i can't use attribute.

Answer (score 1):

here some answer hope solve your problem

#### [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyhh8/1/)

### html

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    I have a tooltip.
    <div class="tooltip">I am a tooltip!</div>
  </div>
```

### css

```
.wrapper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #ececec;
  color: #555;
  cursor: help;
  margin: 100px 75px 10px 75px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper .tooltip {
  background: #1496bb;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  left: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.wrapper .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}  

.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       -o-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

Comment: can we create custom tag. Something like this <tooltip>my text</tooltip>?

Comment: great but it may affect my curremt structure as i have to put <div class="wrapper"> into my page. I prefer the simplest solution

Comment: replace `wrapper` to other name. Done

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways to do this from as simple "title" as mentioned in CBroe's excellent suggestion, to the very elegant method of lukeocom. You could hide a div, and pop it up, and use a plugin. Based on CBroe's and lukeocom's excellent suggestions, I've thrown together a rudimentary example with :after.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uNDWJ/)

CSS

```
ins{
    color:blue; 
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration:none;
    position: relative;
}
ins:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
ins:after {
    content: 'This is the inserted text';
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 10px;
}
ins:hover:after {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

And a question out of pure ignorance, Why did you need to create a new element 'ins'?

Comment: great but I can't see the text popup in my webapp, can u make the popup appear right under the text? No <ins> is the basic tag supported by all browsers. Can we create custome tag like "<tooltip>" or something like that in css ?

Comment: To make it below the text just change the absolute position to     left: 0px; top: 20px; or small variations on the theme. And thanks for the comments on 'ins'. Here's a nice little article on custom elements in HTML5. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/